# sample.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 'A dependent dll was not found'

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, dll

I am trying to run my project using opencv functions .
I am able to build code but not able to debug it in VS2012 OS 32 bit Windows 7, Execution is not hitting to main function while debugging .
And coming out from execution by saying this message :

**`sample.exe' has exited with code -1073741515  'A dependent dll was not found'`**

Can any one know the reason behind .

Note:

I have give dll path also and enable TOOLS->Debugging->Symbols->Microsoft Symbol servers option .

Edit:
Below is the solution for my Question given by H. Guijt ."

`You can use Dependency Walker to figure out which DLLs it needs. dependencywalker.com` 
I checked the dll which were not present in my system with the help of above tool and thus solve this error message . :)

Comment: You can use Dependency Walker to figure out which DLLs it needs. http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: It really helped me to solve my issue !!Thanks

Comment: Please post the answer as an _answer_, not an edit to the question

Answer (score 0):

solution for my Question given by H. Guijt.

`You can use Dependency Walker to figure out which DLLs it needs.`

dependencywalker.com I checked the dll which were not present in my system with the help of above tool and thus solve this error message . :)